# Error display in HttpConnection

Tags: android

I have some problem which is related to HttpConnection and not display images in ViewPager.Errors are displayed as  below.What is solution for it? please guide me.

Link of Images:

```
http:\\\\discoverylearning.in\\gopalj\\images\\img1.png
```

Error:

```
04-07 13:46:59.414: D/gralloc_goldfish(998): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-07 13:47:00.244: D/dalvikvm(998): GC_CONCURRENT freed 194K, 11% free 5995K/6663K, paused 8ms+7ms
04-07 13:47:01.094: E/ImageLoader(998): null
04-07 13:47:01.094: E/ImageLoader(998): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-07 13:47:01.094: E/ImageLoader(998):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.hashCode(HttpConnection.java:343)
04-07 13:47:01.094: E/ImageLoader(998):     at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:298)
04-07 13:47:01.094: E/ImageLoader(998):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:67)
04-07 13:47:01.094: E/ImageLoader(998):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
04-07 13:47:01.094: E/ImageLoader(998):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
04-07 13:47:01.094: E/ImageLoader(998):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
04-07 13:47:01.094: E/ImageLoader(998):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
04-07 13:47:01.094: E/ImageLoader(998):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
04-07 13:47:01.094: E/ImageLoader(998):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
04-07 13:47:01.094: E/ImageLoader(998):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
04-07 13:47:01.094: E/ImageLoader(998):     at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.URLConnectionImageDownloader.getStreamFromNetwork(URLConnectionImageDownloader.java:40)
04-07 13:47:01.094: E/ImageLoader(998):     at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.ImageDownloader.getStream(ImageDownloader.java:25)
04-07 13:47:01.094: E/ImageLoader(998):     at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.saveImageOnDisc(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:231)
04-07 13:47:01.094: E/ImageLoader(998):     at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:139)
04-07 13:47:01.094: E/ImageLoader(998):     at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:72)
04-07 13:47:01.094: E/ImageLoader(998):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
04-07 13:47:01.094: E/ImageLoader(998):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-07 13:47:01.094: E/ImageLoader(998):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-07 13:47:01.094: E/ImageLoader(998):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-07 13:47:01.094: E/ImageLoader(998):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-07 13:47:01.094: E/ImageLoader(998):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-07 13:47:01.824: E/ImageLoader(998): null
```

Comment: Please post your code. Or just show us part of code at where you are getting `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Debug and find where you are getting NullPointerException